Bounding d-regular graph traversal length for every starting node and every traversal
Question: (Past exam question i'm using to revise)
Let $G = (V,E)$. A connected d-regular graph. Let $v_1 \in V$. Assume that at each node, the ends of the edges incident with the node are labelled $1,2,...,d$, in arbitrary order.
A Schrodinger Traversal for a given graph $G$, given a starting node $v_1$ and given a labelling is a sequence $(\ell_1,\ell_2,...,\ell_t)\in\{1,...,d\}^t$ such that if we start a walk at $v_1$ and the $i$-th step we leave the current node through the edge locally labelled $\ell_i$ then we visit every node in $V$
A General Schrodinger Traversal for some $n$ and $d$ is a sequence which is a Schrodinger Traversal for every $d$-regular graph on $n$ vertices, every labelling, and every starting node.
Formally prove that for every $d$ and $n$ large enough there exists a general Schrodinger traversal of length $O(dn^3\log(n))$, given the expected cover time of a random walk in a graph G is $2n^2$
What i've tried:
My first thought was to bound the length of a random variable $X$ such that $|X|$ was the size of a general Schrodinger traversal, to use a Chernoff bound. $$Pr(|X|\geq(1+\delta)E(|X|)) \leq\left(\frac{e^{\delta}}{(\delta+1)^{\delta+1}}\right)^{E(|X|)}$$
Thus giving, $$(1+\delta)E(|X|) = O(dn^3\log{n}) \implies (1+\delta)E(|X|) \geq dn^3\log{n}$$ and to show this must exist,$$\left(\frac{e^{\delta}}{(\delta+1)^{\delta+1}}\right)^{E(|X|)} > 0$$
However i failed at deriving $E(|X|)$ for this step, so i moved on to another approach, attempting to bound this for every individual node, and use a union bound to derive the maximum length of the traversal, but this bound wasn't tight enough nor did it actually prove there existed a traversal of the required size.
